# i got error none of the index are in the column in python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have this problem with juputer notebook when i wright that line in python

*df["AQI"] = df["AQI"].fillna(round(df[["PM2.5_SubIndex", "PM10_SubIndex", "SO2_SubIndex", "NOx_SubIndex","NH3_SubIndex", "CO_SubIndex", "O3_SubIndex"]].max(axis = 1)))*

the whole project here:
 [here](https://github.com/tulseebisen/ML_Projects/blob/main/AirQualityIndex/Air_Quality_Index_RandomForest.ipynb)

the error is :

**KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6320/515642622.py in 
----> 1 default["AQI"] = default["AQI"].fillna(round(default[["PM2.5_SubIndex", "PM10_SubIndex", "SO2_SubIndex", "NOx_SubIndex","NH3_SubIndex", "CO_SubIndex", "O3_SubIndex"]].max(axis = 1)))
2
~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in **getitem**(self, key)
3462             if is_iterator(key):
3463                 key = list(key)
-> 3464             indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1)[1](https://github.com/tulseebisen/ML_Projects/blob/main/AirQualityIndex/Air_Quality_Index_RandomForest.ipynb)
3465
3466         # take() does not accept boolean indexers
~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis)
1312             keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = ax._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
1313
-> 1314         self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis)
1315
1316         if needs_i8_conversion(ax.dtype) or isinstance(
~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis)
1372                 if use_interval_msg:
1373                     key = list(key)
-> 1374                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
1375
1376             not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())

and key error

KeyError: "None of [Index(['PM2.5_SubIndex', 'PM10_SubIndex', 'SO2_SubIndex', 'NOx_SubIndex',\n       'NH3_SubIndex', 'CO_SubIndex', 'O3_SubIndex'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

can anyone explain to me what the error and how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

I think your `axis=1` should be outside of the `max()` function call. You could rewrite is as:

```py
df["AQI"] = df["AQI"].fillna(round(df[["PM2.5_SubIndex", "PM10_SubIndex", "SO2_SubIndex", "NOx_SubIndex","NH3_SubIndex", "CO_SubIndex", "O3_SubIndex"]].max()), axis=1)
```

Comment: I try it same error